# fetch() is not POSTing JSON body

Tags: json, reactjs, fetch-api

The fetch() API is not POSTing this JSON body.

```
var j = {
    "addressee": "James"
};
return fetch('http://requestb.in/blahblahblah', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(j)
})
```

There is absolutely no request body showing up in RequestBin for this. What could be happening to the body? Debugging `JSON.stringify(j)` shows that it is indeed formatting the body correctly.

Comment: Does a request appear in the Network pane in your browser's developer tools?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the fetch() API was sending an OPTIONS preflight request, to see the CORS configuration on the server. Removing the headers in my `fetch()` request stopped this from happening.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by changing

```
<input type="submit" onSubmit={()=>{}}/>
```

to

```
<button type="button" onClick={this.someFunction}>Submit</button>
```

Don't know why, but while using ReactJS developed app in Firefox, this has always worked for me. Without this, the browser simply did not fire the POST request(could not see it in the Developer Options:Network Tab).

Using this remedy, it just worked without doing any other change, started seeing the POST requests.